# Python code simplification? One line, add all in list

Tags: python

I'm making my way through project Euler and I'm trying to write the most concise code I can.  I know it's possible, so how could I simplify the following code.  Preferably, I would want it to be one line and not use the int->string->int conversion.

Question: What is the sum of the digits of the number 2<sup>1000</sup>?

My answer:

```
>>> i=0
>>> for item in [int(n) for n in str(2**1000)];i+=item
```

Comment: Where did `2**1000` come from?

Comment: Why one line, who are you trying to impress?

Comment: @Michael Mrozek 
http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=16

@PreludeAndFugue: myself

Comment: @bball Ah; your question said 21000 originally

Comment: Ah, thank you.  I just copied and pasted from Project Euler.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no way you're going to get rid of the int->string->int conversion

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
sum(int(n) for n in str(2**1000))
```

Comment: For fun, this is the exact same thing:
`sum(int(n) for n in str(1<<1000))`

Comment: better to document the code, cos the next person who reads this would be like "WTF?"

Comment: how is `sum(foo)` less readable than `x=0;for item in foo:x+=item;x` ?

Comment: for fun, sum(map(int,str(2**1000))) ;)

Answer (score 3):

Not a one-liner, but a cleaner-looking generator solution, also avoiding the int->string->int conversion:

```
def asDigits(n):
    while n:
        n,d = divmod(n,10)
        yield d

print sum(asDigits(2**1000))
```

Gives 1366.

Interestingly, the sum of the digits in 2**10000 is 13561, whose digits add up to the same value as 1366.

Of course, if expressed in binary, the sum of the digits in 2**1000 is 1. (I even did it in my head!)

Answer (score 0):

Single int to str conversion to get length:

```
int(sum(map(lambda x:2**1000/x % 10, (10**x for x in xrange(len(str(2**1000)))))))
```